# Query SQL Server from Oracle - force metadata refresh

Tags: sql-server, oracle, dblink

I am a SQL Server developer, with a task in Oracle. DBA set up a DBLink in Oracle that points at a SQL Server database. I am writing a view on the SQL Server data and then a view on the Oracle side to join it with additional Oracle data.

Problem: if I change the definition of the view on SQL Server, even "Select * From myview@dblink" errors with "Invalid column." Closing TOAD and reopening seems to correct the problem, but the real question is how to force Oracle to re-read the metadata without resetting the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the Oracle 10g client. The current solution is to disconnect and reconnect. Given that I haven't been able to find anyone else with this problem, i will assume that it is a problem with my client config.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue with TOAD, not oracle. What happens if you do it in SQL*Plus?

Comment: Same thing happens in SQL*Plus. If I exit and get back in, it works just fine. Must be caching metadata on the connection object.

Next test, I queried the view in TOAD, changed it, queried it again. It failed. Then I opened a second connection. Query ran just fine. Must be on the connection object.

Comment: what happens if you do a commit/rollback in your session?

Comment: Nope. Nothing short of killing the connection forces the metadata refresh. Must be something in the Oracle client configuration - which is controlled by our Operations staff. I will discuss with them.

Thanks Matthew and tuinstoel for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I understand you but if you got a `dblink` that points to a SQL server DB in your Oracle DB and you need data in SQL server just do:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE@dblink

SELECT "COL", "COL2", "COL3
from TABLE@dblink


SELECT T."COL", H."COL"
FROM TABLE1@dblink T, TABLE2@dblink H
WHERE T."ID" = H."ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do?:

```
alter view <<view_name>> compile;
```

I haven't tested this because I have no db link from Oracle to MSSQL.

Comment: I will try first thing on Monday.